# Seriously stumped with WOW.js and integrating with animate.css

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm working on putting together a portfolio site. It's coming along nicely, but I've hit a real shag.

I'm using one page, and have made four divs thus far to break up my work. I'll have graphic design pieces coming in from one side or the other as the user scrolls.

Now, I found WOW.js which is supposed to do precisely what I want it to, ie. make a graphic of mine show up only when the user scrolls down to it. BUT for the life of me, I cannot get it to work, and it's supposed to be so simple, doge style. Such amaze!

The graphic in question is a heart, and animate.css has a great 'pulse' bit of CSS I want to use. WOW.js is supposed to be fabulously with animate.css. But I'm completely lost. My JS skills are still very basic, so please be patient.

As the WOW.js docs state, I've linked to it with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
```

(my CSS folder is named public, but I can't see that making a difference...?)

This goes at the bottom of my index page:

```
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>
```

I added the CSS class to an HTML element like so:

```
<div class="wow">  Content to Reveal Here  </div >
```

Then you're supposed to add the animate.css style to the element:

```
<div class="wow pulse">  Content to Reveal Here  </div >
```

But I'm missing something, because nothing is working. I've googled this and I'm not the only person who's had issues with WOW.js, but I've tried everything, and now I turn to you.

Under the customize settings on the docs, it suggests advanced settings:

```
wow = new WOW(
    {
    boxClass:     'wow',      // default
    animateClass: 'animated', // default
    offset:       0          // default
   }
)
wow.init();
```

I'm thinking since this isn't SO AMAZE at all, there's gotta be another way for me to do this, but still be able to use a CSS animation.

LAST question: how do I make the pulse animation continue? It pulses a few times, then stops, but I want it to continue over and over. Suggestions?

Comment: The `href` tag needs to point to the CSS file.  You say you have it in a folder named "public", so it should be `href="public/animate.css"`, not `href="css/animate.css"`

Comment: That was my error. My actual code does have it correctly typed as      href="public/animate.css"

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: I completely forgot to check console! Ok, I have two ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND messages. One is javascript/index.js. I'm pretty sure I deleted that file as I thought I no longer needed it. But that's probably *not* the case. The second error is really confusing me, as it's looking for a file under my github.io folder called js/wow.min.js. I have no idea what that is. Lastly, the final error says "WOW not defined". That makes sense, but I'm not sure what/how I should define it.

Answer (score 13):

Just put this code in your index:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/0.1.12/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>new WOW().init();</script>
```

no need to call for

```
<script src="wow.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wish I had seen your answer an hour ago Gary. I used your code, and slightly updated version and it fixed my problem immediately.  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script><script>new WOW().init();</script>

Answer (score 0):

couple things are happening here:

`</div >` is not a proper closing for an html tag.

if WOW is not defined then you most likely didn't include `wow.js` - make sure you have the right file (see what is inside) and the correct path. When you get stuck - Get rid of ALL console errors and make a minimum, bare bone solution that should work - it is less confusing and easier to find what is causing troubles.

as for repeating pulse animation - just don't. In the old days there were those [`<blink>`](https://www.google.com/search?q=blink%20tag) and [`<marquee>`](https://www.google.com/search?q=marquee%20tag) tags and they are gone for a reason - you shouldn't use it. Same goes for [Comic Sans](http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/) unless your site is about doge.

now, the following example worked for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="wow.js"></script>
<script>
  new WOW().init();
</script>
<img  src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19020828/heavy3.jpg" /><br>

<div class="wow  bounceInUp">
<img  src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19020828/heavy3.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="wow pulse">
<img  src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19020828/heavy3.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej. I will let you know how this progresses.

Also, the code I posted is a direct copy and paste from the developer's website, so that's where the closing </div> came from.